# My body tag wont extend to the bottom of my page

Tags: html, css, height

I´ve been searching the interweb for two days, but have not been able to figure this out. I am making a webpage with loads of included php files, and I have been asked to make a footer with contact information etc.

The problem is that i can´t get the footer to stick to the bottom, and I have discovered that it´s because the body doesn´t extend all the way to the bottom of the page.

Comment: The code on that page is a complete disaster. You are stacking full pages of html code on top of each other.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.radiosor.no%2FmainContent.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 - disaster.

Comment: They are full htmlpages that are included with php.

Comment: Hyperpedro: you shouldn't do that.

Comment: I have removed the html framework, so i´m only including the content. Seems that the html/body /wrapper only goes down to where I start to include my files.

Answer (score 2):

See this link for a solution: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/
Made with pure CSS :)

The body element doesn´t have a height like you think of it, it is as height as the elements in it.

Comment: I have actually tried this solution, and it dosn´t seem to do anything with the page. It works on other webpages i have made, but not on this one.

Comment: @Hyperpedro - first make your html valid (atleast eliminate all structural errors like omited closing tags, incorrectly nested elements) and than you can start implementing the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a link that perfectly answers your question, that is "Stay On Top" script at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/stayontop.htm

Comment: Thanks for all the help, guys. I cleaned up the code and did some adjustments to the content, and it´s now working quite good:)